# wsdlLocation not picking up wsdl

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a VERY simple Spring WS with CFX.  The familiar HelloWorld example. Everything works fine, except the wsdlLocation of the jaxws:endpoint.  my bean definition looks like this:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="helloTest"
  implementor="com.michael.ws.HelloImpl"
  address="Hello"
  wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/Hello.wsdl" >
  <jaxws:properties>
    <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
  </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Now as you might expect,  Hello?wsdl  produces the wsdl,  but NOT the one that is in WEB-INF/wsdl

It's like the CFXServlet is taking over and no matter what I put in wsdlLocation means nothing...  in fact, I did put junk in there, and I got no errors at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try using below, This tells the plugin that the wsdl will be on the classpath instead of an absolute path.

```
wsdlLocation="classpath:wsdl/Hello.wsdl"
```

Also try checking the cxf maven plugin declaration that has the wsdloptions

```
<wsdlOption> <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/FooService.wsdl</wsdl> <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/FooService.wsdl</wsdlLocation> </wsdlOption>
```

Comment: Updated with another approach where in you can declare the relative path image the cxf maven plugin declaration

Comment: I don't use the plugin.  And I am not building a client. This is server only.